Interactive image segmentation training tool
I have a bunch of 2D grayscale images for which I want to train a (multi-label) segmentation model. What is the simplest way to interactively train such a model?
I.e., I want to:

Label a (very) few images manually
Train / finetune a model on those segmentation masks
Iteratively refine / retrain that model by going through more images + correcting the predicted masks

I know of methods such as DeepEdit, DeepGrow etc. and I technically understand how they work.
However, I am looking for the simplest (most time-efficient) way and tool to do this in practice without having to code things myself.
Active learning would be a plus but isn't required.

Here are three similar software for interactively training segmentation models:

ilastik
Labkit
Apoc


Thanks! The first two kind of look like what I was searching for, but from the tutorial pages I'm not yet sure they allow for refining the classifier over multiple different images? I.e., it looks as if the classifier is only trained based on scribbles on a single image?

Using ilastik, for example, you can open many images at once, say, all the images in a directory (see here https://www.ilastik.org/documentation/basics/dataselection). It may probably interpret them as frames in a movie, but it will not be a problem if the interpretation is wrong. What is important is that they will all be open at once, and adding annotations on any image will update the model, and the live/interactive prediction for all the open images.f
